# Prove: If $f(x)$ is $\Omega(g(x))$ and $g(x)$ is $\Omega(h(x))$, then $f(x)$ is $\Omega(h(x))$. Use definitions of asymptotic.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Prove: If $f(x)$ is $\Omega(g(x))$ and $g(x)$ is $\Omega(h(x))$, then $f(x)$ is $\Omega(h(x))$. Use definitions of asymptotic.

I know our given is: $f(x)=\Omega(g(x))$, and $g(x)=\Omega(h(x))$.

And we need: $f(x)=\Omega(h(x))$.

I know the rule of $\Omega$ is $f(x)\geq Ag(x)$ for all real numbers $x > a$, and we have two of those. so we need an $A_1$, and an $A_2$.

From here I'm not sure how to prove the if then statement.

Answer (score 1):

You know that $f(x) \ge Ag(x)$ for all $x > a$, where $a$ is some real number, and $A$ is a positive constant. You also know that $g(x) \ge Bh(x)$ for some positive constant $B$ and all $x > b$, where $b$ is some real number. Thus combining the two inequalities (since $A$ is positive): $$f(x) \ge ABh(x)$$ for all $x > \max(a, b)$. This is the same as $f = \Omega(h)$.